# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel in unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm using dagger-hilt with hilt jetpack integration

**My production dependencies**

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28"

implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

**My test dependencies**

```
testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

testImplementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'
kaptTest 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

Now in my Activity, I'm using `by viewModels()` extension form jetpack

```kotlin
private val viewModel: SplashViewModel by viewModels()
```

And in my ViewModel, I'm using `@ViewModelInject` from jetpack

```kotlin
class SplashViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val authenticationRepository: AuthenticationRepository
)
```

It's working fine in production code, but when launching the activity from a test using Robolectric the app will crash with this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.SplashViewModel
```

This is my test class

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1], application = TestApplication::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class SplashActivityTest {

    private val authenticationRepository: AuthenticationRepository = mockk(relaxed = true)

    @get:Rule
    val rule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule
    var activityRule = IntentsTestRule(SplashActivity::class.java)
}
```

And this is my `TestApplication` class

```kotlin
class TestApplication : MultiDexApplication(), GeneratedComponentManager<Any>,
    TestApplicationComponentManagerHolder {

    private var componentManager: TestApplicationComponentManager? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        componentManager = TestApplicationComponentManager(this)
    }

    override fun componentManager(): Any? {
        return componentManager
    }

    override fun generatedComponent(): Any {
        return componentManager!!.generatedComponent()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when launching an Activity from a test case, it's a "normal" Activity and not a Hilt Activity annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

In order to solve this problem you have to (1) create a `@AndroidEntryPoint` Activity that you launch, (2) create debug scenario for that.

Here is an easy tutorial for all the things you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4zG93ogWFY&t and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-dJTFeOAqw&t

Answer (score 0):

Use **public** to declare SplashViewModel class like

```
public class SplashViewModel extends ViewModel {
    // TODO: Implement the ViewModel
}
```

Comment: It's already public, I'm using Kotlin not Java. in Kotlin all classes are public by default